# Event tracking in Google Analytics. Codes in right place?

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I need your help in order to find out why Google Analytics is not tracking 3 events I created.

Please check the source code for http://www.zulamian.com/, and look for the following lines of code.

Are the event tracking codes in the right place?

1) Contact form submission tracking:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Contacto', 'Consultar', 'Formulario de Consulta', 0, false]);
```

2) CV submission form tracking:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'CV', 'Enviar CV', 'Formulario de CV', 0, false]);
```

3) Newsletter signup form submission tracking:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Boletin', 'Suscribirse a Boletin', 'Formulario de Boletin', 0, false]);
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Perhaps GA is not tracking because the GA code is placed in the footer instead of the header? Thanks.

Comment: I just tried your contact form, and I was able to see a hit to GA for an event being fired. You can take a look at this by using something like the developer tools in Chrome or FireBug in Firefox. In the Network tab, look for a hit to __utm.gif ... once you do the action that should result in an event. The query string parameters will show you the details of the event. Are you still not seeing them show up?